# Python Dictionaries, Keys, and Strings

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

I'm trying to write a program that takes a variable, containing a dictionary, where keys are one word strings and values are lists of strings. Each string is a definition for the word/key.

What I want to do is ask the user for a word; if it's not in the dict. then I display an error message, if it is, then I print out each of the definitions, numbered starting at 1.

I have trouble understanding how I can call the different definitions on different lines and numbering them. This is what I have so far:

```
def Dict(webdict):
    word_user = raw_input('Word ==> ')
    i =0
    if word_user in webdict:
        while i <= len(webdict['word_user']):
            print str(i+1) + '.', webdict['word_user'][i]
            i+=1
    else:
        print '"' + word_user + '"', 'not found in webdict.'

Dict(webdict)
```

Some example outputs:

```
Word ==> python
1. a large heavy-bodied nonvenomous constrictor snake occurring throughout the Old World tropics
2. a high-level general-purpose programming language

Word ==> constrictor
Word “constrictor” not found in webster
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you index `webdict`, the key should be `word_user`, not `'word_user'`. The latter is a string literal, rather than whatever the user typed.
2. Your `while` loop goes one past the end of the list. Change the `<=` to `<`, or just use a `for` loop with `enumerate`.

```
def Dict(webdict):
    word_user = raw_input('Word ==> ')
    i =0
    if word_user in webdict:
        while i < len(webdict[word_user]):
            print str(i+1) + '.', webdict[word_user][i]
            i+=1
    else:
        print '"' + word_user + '"', 'not found in webdict.'

webdict = {"Python": ["A cool snake", "A cool language"]}
Dict(webdict)
```

Or

```
def Dict(webdict):
    word_user = raw_input('Word ==> ')
    if word_user in webdict:
        for i, definition in enumerate(webdict[word_user], 1):
            print str(i+1) + '.', definition
    else:
        print '"' + word_user + '"', 'not found in webdict.'

webdict = {"Python": ["A cool snake", "A cool language"]}
Dict(webdict)
```

Result:

```
Word ==> Python
1. A cool snake
2. A cool language
```

Comment: `enumerate` has a start number, so the `+1` is unnecessary. Also `i=0` is a left-over.